# loop through vlookup with VBA

Tags: vba, vlookup

I am not an expert in VBA, so I stumble into a problem now!

I have a sheet with a button (say update sintetic*)
* sintetic is the name of the workbook to be updated

I need to update sintetic through a vlookup formula, which is working fine, this is the code:

```
  Sub update sintetic()
    '

'

'disable everything so macro goes faster
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

'opens the workbook to be written
    Windows("sintetic.xlsx").Activate

'formula goes here
    Range("c2").FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=VLOOKUP(RC[-2]&RC[-1],'[Gross.xlsb]dados'!C39:C40,2,0)"
    Range("c3").FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=VLOOKUP(RC[-2]&RC[-1],'[Gross.xlsb]dados'!C39:C40,2,0)"

'breaks the link
    ActiveWorkbook.BreakLink Name:= _
        "gross.xlsb", Type:=xlExcelLinks

'enables everything again
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = True

End Sub
```

The problem is: I need to update 900 cells, in the code above, I am updating only 2 cells ( c2 and c3)I don´t want to copy and paste 900 lines, so, is there a way to loop through a range with the code above? Say c1:c1000, also, the 100 cells that will not be found should be blank.

This is a very specific request, so I found nothing to help me, if anyone can shed a light, it would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a loop or more lines.  `FormulaR1C1` allows for applying the formula en masse.

```
Range("C2:C900").FormulaR1C1 = _
  "=VLOOKUP(RC[-2]&RC[-1],'[Gross.xlsb]dados'!C39:C40,2,0)"
```

Comment: Fantastic! That´s brilliant

Comment: what @scott said, and you should fully qualify the range that you are setting.... like this `Workbooks("sintetic.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C2:C900").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-2]&RC[-1],'[Gross.xlsb]dados'!C39:C40,2,0)"`